# image not uploading if first of the array index is empty

Tags: php, file-upload, foreach

i am trying to upload multiple photos using php. everything working fine. but the problem is the array containing images not uploading if any of the field is blank.
Here is my code:

```
$count = 0;

foreach ($_FILES['myfile']['name'] as $key=>$filename){


$filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$count];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// echo $ext;
// exit();
if($ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "gif"){

        $filename = uploadfilename($filename);  
        $filename1=$iiid."blog".$filename;
        $target_path = "../photo/";

        $target_path = $target_path . repc($filename1);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path);    
        $dbfield = $count+1;           
        $sql="update product set img_".$dbfield." ='".rep($filename1)."' where id='".$iiid."'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $count++;
        // header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        // print_r(get_resource_type($uploadedImage));exit();
        // $resizedImage = PIPHP_ImageResize($target_path,400,400);
        $w = 400;
        $h = 400;
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($target_path);
        $info = getimagesize($target_path);
        $mime = $info['mime'];
        switch ($mime) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $source = ImageCreateFromJPEG($target_path);
                $resized_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);        
                ImageCopyResampled($resized_img, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
                ImageJPEG($resized_img,$target_path);
                ImageDestroy($resized_img);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $source = ImageCreateFromPNG($target_path);
                $resized_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);
                ImageCopyResampled($resized_img, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
                ImagePNG($resized_img,$target_path);
                ImageDestroy($resized_img);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $source = ImageCreateFromGIF($target_path);
                $resized_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);        
                ImageCopyResampled($resized_img, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
                ImageGIF($resized_img,$target_path);
                ImageDestroy($resized_img);
                break;        
            default : echo "unknown file";
                exit();
            }
    }
}
```

i am sending images using input type file. in the $_FILES array if first index element is blank and other index are not then the loop not working. please help

Comment: I suppose that code is within some loop, could you post the code in such a way that it contain the loop around?

Comment: my guess would be the last case within the `switch` statement - using `exit` and unknown file / blank entry would cause it to exit. Also - the `mysql` api is deprecated and removed from current/future versions of PHP

Comment: what should i write in the default section?

Comment: You can log the error, but don't exit(), that's stopping the execution.

Comment: @RamRaider, your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Nowhereman, removed the exit after default. but still not working.

Comment: You should never build queries by concatenating strings. This is a major security risk, as it opens you to SQL Injection attacks.
I.e. Never do this : 

`$sql="update product set img_".$dbfield." ='".rep($filename1)."' where id='".$iiid."'";`
Alway use some type of parametrised query.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can try, that doesn't need you to find exactly where the problem might be in the code, is to surround each iteration of the loop with a `try` / `catch`.

That way, if any iteration fails by throwing an exception, it won't prevent the rest of the code to execute.

You need to be careful, though, that no exception be thrown before you advance whatever marks the iteration. Here, you have a `$count++;` smack in the middle of the iteration, if anything fails before that line, your code will get stuck. (it is good style anyway to not mix codes that do different things; you should put that line either at the very beginning or at the very end; at the very beginning with the `try` / `catch` strategy)

Answer (score 0):

when i remove the (if $ext==) condition from the code it works fine.

Comment: try `$ext=strtolower( pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );`

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of your first index is empty, the code doesn't go inside the if loop and the value of '$count' doesn't get incremented. 
So, the value of $count is '0', always.

Try putting '$count++' after the end of if loop.